# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: mysql

SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I have tried to put in single line neglecting white spaces but still its showing!

ACTUALL CODE THAT I WROTE IS BELOW

```
select first_name,last_name 
from employees 
where salary = (select min(salary) 
               from employees 
               where department_id IN (select distinct(department_id) 
                                      from departments);
```

Comment: You really don't like JOINs, do you! Also, note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Add one more closing brace at end

```
select first_name
     , last_name 
  from employees
 where salary = 
     (select min(salary) 
        from employees 
      where department_id IN (select distinct(department_id) from departments)) ;
```

Comment: When the answer is "you are missing a closing brace", the accepted practice is that there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this question has no value to other users. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)